# Cannot find module ''npm-registry-fetch'

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, npm-install

I try to install the sentiment package for node.js

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I get the following err message:

> npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
>
> npm ERR! Cannot find module 'npm-registry-fetch'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> ...

Up so far

- I have searched in web for a solution without success
- I deleted the npm cache und reinstalled node.js but the error still exist. Who has an idea?

I use windows 10

> npm config list
>
> ; cli configs
>
> metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
>
> scope = ""
>
> user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v10.13.0 win32 x64"
>
> ; builtin config undefined
>
> prefix = "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm"
>
> ; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
>
> ; cwd = C:\Users\username\SentimentKI
>
> ; HOME = C:\Users\username
>
> ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

Comment: This is how you tried right? => `npm i npm-registry-fetch`

Comment: yes, this i also tried

Comment: Better uninstall your `node.js` and try re-installing it, in most of the case it works that way.

Comment: can you show me the output of command --> npm config list

Comment: David, I already deinstalled und re-installed node.js twice. The error still exist.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem. I needed to delete the following directories:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

After that I deinstalled note und installed it again.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also re install your current node version, if you are using n as node version manager, you can run

```
n prune
```

to uninstall all node versions except latest and then run

```
n 8.11.3
```

to install node version number 8.11.3.

Maybe it's not the best solution but it's quicklier